# iterate the range in for loop to satisfy the condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

According to answered solutions I have tested the loop. I want the range swtich from 6 to 10; 11 to 16 and so one until  the condition is satisfied but the loop keep running from 1 to 5.

```
set_mean = -10
#calculated_mean = None

energy = []
calculated_mean = float('inf')
while calculated_mean > set_mean:
        for i in range(1, 5):  
           energy.append(i-i*i)  
           print(energy)
           calculated_mean =  sum(energy[-2:])/2
           print(calculated_mean)
```

How I can automate the range so that it switch to next five values in second loop and so on if the condition is not satisfied. For this example, it will satisfied if loop will run from 6 to 10. 
Thanks!

Comment: Is indentation correct or just here? After **for** loop

Comment: i think it is here. On my system it is working.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear

Comment: i want to run loop over range values. In this case; my loop range is from (1,5) which gives me -9 calculated_mean. Now I want run the loop from (6,10) and so on until calculated_mean is less than set_mean. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Currently your code runs into infinite state

Comment: yes, due to small range (1-5) it would not give me required mean and keep on running. so i want the code to switch range from 6-10 if condition is not satisfied. It is something step size to be added after each loop until condition is satisfied.

Comment: Please refer to my answer below

Comment: inf is nothing. Even without it, i got the same. One of fellow wrote me code with inf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you are just asking to do the dynamic way use the following:

```
set_mean = -10
#calculated_mean = None

energy = []
calculated_mean = float('inf')
x = 1
while calculated_mean > set_mean:
    for i in range(x, x+4):  # you can change step size here by passing it as last argument
        energy.append(i-i*i)  
        print(energy)
        calculated_mean =  sum(energy[-2:])/2
        print(calculated_mean)
    x = x + 1
```

**Output is:**

```
[0]
0
[0, -2]
-1
[0, -2, -6]
-4
[0, -2, -6, -12]
-9
[0, -2, -6, -12, -2]
-7
[0, -2, -6, -12, -2, -6]
-4
[0, -2, -6, -12, -2, -6, -12]
-9
[0, -2, -6, -12, -2, -6, -12, -20]
-16
```

I think this is exactly what you want. Because the loop stops when you get **-16**

Comment: this is right. but Can I control step size. Like this one check the condition after one step. I want to run the program for next complete loop before going to check condition. Thank you for this. I will try this.

Comment: Perhaps `x = x + 5` would be better. Adding 1 will be the consecutive ranges will be `1-5`, `2-6`, ... Whereas OP asked for step size be 5 (rather than 1).

Comment: @Dunes YEs. But he had changed his question a bit later :-)

Answer (score -1):

i don't see any conditionals, this loop will run forever as of your current version since **calculated_mean** will always be greater than **set_mean** since you are making the **energy** list larger every time you go through the loop, i don't really understand what your "condition" for calculates_mean is but if it's just the average of the last 2 numbers in the list it will never be greater than your set_mean which will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: I made an arbitrary example to test. If the range switch to 6-10 then this condition is satisfied. This is what I want to know how program run loop 2nd time from 6 to 10.